# ¿Como hacer funcionar un onclick poniendo todo el codigo en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo me gustaría dejar todo el html sin apenas código javascript como mucho el código que una la pagina de html y javascript, pero tengo la duda de si se podía hacer que todo el código del uso de onclick se pudiera hacer solo en javascript y solo poniendo el id en los inputs correspondientes para llamar a la función.
De momento le doy al boton y no funciona, pero tampoco da ningún error, directamente es como si no lo reconociese.
Dicho esto aqui dejo el codigo html y javacript

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("abre").onclick = abrir;
    document.getElementById("colores").onclick = generarcolor;
    document.getElementById("horario").onclick = horario;
}

console.log(onload);

var ventana;

function abrir() {
    console.log(abrir);
    ventana = window.open("", "new_window", "width=800,height=500,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no");
    contar();
}

window.onload = contar //para que cuando 
var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

console.log(abrir);

function contar() {
    if (ventana) {
        ventana.document.write(" <span id = contador></span>") //quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador
        ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
        if (contartiempo == 0) {
            ventana.close();
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            contartiempo -= 1;
            setTimeout("contar()", 1000);
        }

    }
}
console.log(contar);

function generarcolor() {

    var simbolo = "1234567890ABCDEF";

    var color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        color = color + simbolo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

    }

    document.body.style.background = color;
    document.getElementById("nombrecolor").innerHTML = color;
}
console.log(generarcolor);


function horario() {

    const hoy = new Date();
    let h = hoy.getHours();
    let m = hoy.getMinutes();
    let s = hoy.getSeconds();
    m = comprobar(m);
    s = comprobar(s);


    var fecha = new Date();
    var dia_semana = [
        "Domingo",
        "Lunes",
        "Martes",
        "Miércoles",
        "Jueves",
        "Viernes",
        "Sabado"
    ];

    var mes = [
        "Enero",
        "Febrero",
        "Marzo",
        "Abril",
        "Mayo",
        "Junio",
        "Julio",
        "Agosto",
        "Septiembre",
        "Octubre",
        "Noviembre",
        "Diciembre"
    ];

    var obtener_fecha=  dia_semana[fecha.getDay()] + ", " +fecha.getDate() + " de "+mes[fecha.getMonth()]+ " del " + fecha.getFullYear();



    document.getElementById('imprimir').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s +" - " +obtener_fecha ;
    setTimeout(horario, 1000);
}

function comprobar(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
    }; //añade cero delante de los numeros mayores de 10
    return i;//La sentencia return finaliza la ejecución de la función y especifica un valor para ser devuelto a quien llama a la función.
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Abrir" id="abre">
<input type="button" value="elegir color" id="colores">
<span id="nombrecolor">#E8347D</span>
<input type="button" value="horario" id="horario">
<h2 id="imprimir"></h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas sobre escribiendo onload con esta linea:

```
window.onload = contar //para que cuando
```

Comentala y todo funcionara bien.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 
  document.getElementById("abre").onclick = abrir;
  document.getElementById("colores").onclick = generarcolor;
  document.getElementById("horario").onclick = horario;
  
  //Aqui deberia ir contar
  contar()
}

console.log(onload);


var ventana;

function abrir() {
  console.log(abrir);


  ventana = window.open("", "new_window", "width=800,height=500,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no");

  contar();
}

//Estas sobreescribiendo el onload con esta linea. 
//window.onload = contar //para que cuando 
var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

console.log(abrir);


function contar() {
  if (ventana) {

    ventana.document.write(" <span id = contador></span>") //quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador
    ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
    if (contartiempo == 0) {
      ventana.close();
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      contartiempo -= 1;
      setTimeout("contar()", 1000);
    }

  }
}
console.log(contar);


function generarcolor() {

  var simbolo = "1234567890ABCDEF";

  var color = "#";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

    color = color + simbolo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

  }

  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.getElementById("nombrecolor").innerHTML = color;
}
console.log(generarcolor);


function horario() {

  const hoy = new Date();
  let h = hoy.getHours();
  let m = hoy.getMinutes();
  let s = hoy.getSeconds();
  m = comprobar(m);
  s = comprobar(s);


  var fecha = new Date();
  var dia_semana = [
    "Domingo",
    "Lunes",
    "Martes",
    "Miércoles",
    "Jueves",
    "Viernes",
    "Sabado"
  ];

  var mes = [
    "Enero",
    "Febrero",
    "Marzo",
    "Abril",
    "Mayo",
    "Junio",
    "Julio",
    "Agosto",
    "Septiembre",
    "Octubre",
    "Noviembre",
    "Diciembre"
  ];

  var obtener_fecha = dia_semana[fecha.getDay()] + ", " + fecha.getDate() + " de " + mes[fecha.getMonth()] + " del " + fecha.getFullYear();



  document.getElementById('imprimir').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " - " + obtener_fecha;
  setTimeout(horario, 1000);
}

function comprobar(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; //añade cero delante de los numeros mayores de 10
  return i; //La sentencia return finaliza la ejecución de la función y especifica un valor para ser devuelto a quien llama a la función.
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Abrir" id="abre">
<input type="button" value="elegir color" id="colores">
<span id="nombrecolor">#E8347D</span>
<input type="button" value="horario" id="horario">
<h2 id="imprimir"></h2>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no habia caido en que solo se puede o debe poner un onload.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Legna ya te da la solución a tu problema, pero por completitud me gustaría añadir que ese problema se quitaría si en lugar de usar `elemento.on... = function(...) {...}` para asignar "observadores de eventos", podrías usar `addEventListener`, ya que permite asignar más de uno sin problemas:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

function hazAlgo() {
  console.log('click detectado');
  contador++;
}

let contador = 0;
function hazAlgoMas() {
  document.querySelector('p').innerText = `Clickado ${contador} veces`;
}

button.addEventListener('click', hazAlgo);
button.addEventListener('click', hazAlgoMas);
```

```html
<button>Click aquí</button>
<p>Texto inicial</p>
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por le consejo